# SUM generated_sequence in PostgreSQL 13.0

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have something like that, i need to get "triangular" number - created by summing all natural ones from 0 to n.
I have such code, what should i write so i could
SUM(generate_series from generate_series(1,n))?

```
SELECT n,
    CASE 
      WHEN n > 0 THEN
        SUM value FROM generate_series(1,n)
      ELSE 0
    END
  AS res
FROM triangular
```

Result should be like this: (n-1 , res-1/ n-2, res-3/ n-3, res-6) or in other words: for(res=0;n>0;n--){res=res+n;}
I`m trying to generate_serise and sum it.

I tried to find "adecvate" PostgreSQL documentation wikilike to see returning table "attributes" of generate_sequence "class"

Now, i`ve got this:

```
SELECT n,
    SUM(generate_s::INTEGER)
  AS res
FROM triangular,
  LATERAL generate_series(0,CASE WHEN n<=0 THEN 0 ELSE triangular.n END) 
    AS generate_ser(generate_s)
GROUP BY n
```

How do i replace GROUP BY so its doesnt group it by any way it does it, only the way n value enters the processing code? Kinda how to group values, without ordering them?

Solution:
SELECT n,
sumr.generate_s::BIGINT
AS res
FROM triangular,
LATERAL (SELECT SUM(gen_s) as generate_s FROM generate_series(0,CASE WHEN n<=0 THEN 0 ELSE triangular.n END)
AS gen_ser(gen_s)) sumr

Comment: It is not quite clear, what you are expecting. Could you please add a sample input and output?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77410657/22846972
@S-man
I need to sum returned column of generated sequence

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77410583/sum-generated-sequence-in-postgresql-13-0#comment136470063_77410583
n - 1, res -1/ n - 2, res - 3/ n -3, res -6/ n-4, res - 10/ for(res=0;n>0;n--){res = res+n}

Comment: Could you edit your question and share the expected output ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you searching for the cumulative `SUM()` [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html)?

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wP2IZaSM)

```
SELECT
    x,
    SUM(x) OVER (ORDER BY x) 
FROM generate_series(1, 10) AS x  -- second parameter is n
```

or a simple aggregation?

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YrB8NHVU)

```
SELECT
    SUM(x)
FROM generate_series(1, 10) AS x  -- second parameter is n
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't supply an alias, the name is just "generate_series".  I don't know where this is documented, but it is discoverable by using `*` and looking at the header:

```
select * from generate_series(1,1);
 generate_series
-----------------
               1
```

Or if you assign a column alias, then that is the name:

```
select * from generate_series(1,1) as foo(bar);
 bar
-----
   1
```

If you supply a table alias but not a column alias, then the column name is a copy of the table name.

```
select * from generate_series(1,1) as foo;
 foo
-----
   1
```